# JAMS Scheduler: No such host is known

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I've been given a task to update a C# tool that works with the JAMS scheduler tool, and I've only heard good things about JAMS in spite of my complete inability to install or get it to work at all. I haven't been able to find anything online about this problem, so I know it must be something stupid that I'm doing. (I come from a mac/unix background and everything on windows seems fairly foreign to me)

I've gone through (multiple) successful installs of the JAMS x64 demo, but when I open the Windows JAMS Client GUI, I get consistently get an error popup saying:

```
Unable to load specified root folder: \
Exception:System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): No such host is known
   at System.Net.Dns.InternalGetHostByName(String hostName, Boolean includeIPv6)
   at System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(String hostNameOrAddress)
   at MVPSI.JAMS.Server.GetURL(String objectURL)
   at MVPSI.JAMS.Server.GetRemoteObject[T](String objName)
   at MVPSI.JAMS.Server.Connect()
   at MVPSI.JAMS.Server.GetRemoteObject[T](String objName)
   at MVPSI.JAMS.Folder.Check(Int32& folderID, String folderName, FolderAccess access, Server js)
   at JAMSWin.FolderNavigatorCtl.LoadRootFolder(String folderAddress) in c:\ProductionAZ\JAMS\Release\V6.1\JAMSWin\FolderNavigatorCtl.cs:line 406
```

I believe this error is caused by the JAMS server service using an incorrect server name, but I've tried many combinations (I've also installed/setup JAMS dbs in both my SQL2008 database engine and SqlExpress):

- (local)
- (local)\SqlExpress (with various capitalizations though I don't think this matters, does it?)
- (local)\SQL2008
- domainName\SqlExpress
- ... (the list goes on. Some of them were entirely impossible and I shouldn't have tried them, such as SQLEXPRESS\JAMS, but in my panic I did try it.)

No matter what I enter as the server name, I get the same result - the popup, and then the GUI window comes up saying **"Unable to connect to the JAMSServer service; No such host is known."**

This is all local, so I don't think it is a connectivity problem.

Any help would be greatly, greatly appreciated.

Comment: to downvoters: are the tags inappropriate, is the question inappropriate? should I ask on a different stack exchange site, or somewhere else entirely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

blue - full disclosure here as I work for JAMS.

Without seeing your logs here, it's a little difficult to say for sure what could be going wrong, my best guess is you're defining the SQL Server as the Server the client is connecting to, rather than just your local machine. The Client is trying to connect to the JAMS Server which in turn is trying to talk to SQL.

There is a Red J at the upper left hand corner of the product, if you click there and then on "Servers" you can define the JAMS Server you're trying to talk to. As you mentioned this is all local, simply utilize "localhost" and you should be off to the races.

If you're still having issues, I'd recommend sending in your logs to support for review because there may be something else going on here, it's too tough to say at the moment.

Devon

Comment: Thank you! I had it in my head that I needed to specify the database name as well in the server entry when clicking on the red J. I'm fairly new to databases in general, and this had me pretty confused. Thank you. What a simple problem.